# Get a list of every value for a given key in a set of dictionaries?

Tags: c#

How can I write this code more cleanly/concisely?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a set of valid URIs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="levelVariantURIDicts">A collection of dictionaries of the form:
    ///                                     dict["filePath"] == theFilePath </param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private ICollection<string> URIsOfDicts(ICollection<IDictionary<string, string>> levelVariantURIDicts)
    {
        ICollection<string> result = new HashSet<string>();
        foreach (IDictionary<string, string> dict in levelVariantURIDicts)
        {
            result.Add(dict["filePath"]);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select `dict["filePath"]` for each `dict` in `levelVariantURIDicts` with [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx):

```
return levelVariantURIDicts.Select(dict => dict["filePath"])
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

Drop `.Distinct()` if duplicate entries in the result are fine.
Drop `.ToList()` if you don't really need to return an ICollection<T> and an IEnumerable<T> is fine.

Comment: That is glorious. Thank you so much.